# Time delay an external RSS feed

Tags: rss

I subscribe to a number of RSS feeds, mostly from within my own timezone (UK: currently GMT+1, a.k.a BST). However I'm also interested in news from New Zealand (currently GMT+12).

My problem is caused by my addiction to needing to keep my unread count at, or near, zero.
When I load up my RSS reader in the mornings it has gathered all the NZ news at once (normally around 100 items) and I feel compelled either to read them all or to mark them all as read to feed my need for zero-unread-count.

I figured a good solution to this would be to time delay the RSS feed somehow, so I would be drip-fed the stories at their time +12 hours, so I could read them through the day as they come in.

So my question (or, rather, questions): Does such a thing exist currently & what is it? (no point reworking the wheel) 
If not: What would be the best way to approach doing this myself? I have access to a Linux web server on which I can run scripts, create databases, store files etc, so there should be a way...

I'm most conversant in perl and have done a little fiddling with XML within that, so would naturally process ... or is there some simpler way to do it that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd love a new way to do this (since yahoo pipes is gone) if anyone has one...And ideally something that would work with a six months offset (to get Northern Hemisphere recipe blogs into the right seasonality for the Southern Hemisphere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like something you can do with Yahoo! Pipes (http://pipes.yahoo.com), you might want to explore that. Once you familiarize yourself there, take a look at the Date Builder and filtering options.

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I did. I managed to get one working pretty quickly - certainly quicker than if I'd done it in perl!

URL Builder -> Fetch Feed -> Filter -> Pipe Output. Also a Date Builder feeding into the Filter with "11 hours ago" as parameter.

Comment: Yahoo Pipes  shut down five years ago, this is no longer a viable solution.